# Why doesn't Python 2.7 let me implicitly re-raise an exception after yield?

Tags: python, python-2.7, generator

I've noticed some strange behavior in Python 2.7.5 when yielding inside an `except:` block:

```
def generator():
    try:
        raise Exception()
    except:
        yield
        raise

list(generator())
```

This code fails with `TypeError: exceptions must be old-style classes or derived from BaseException, not NoneType`

Why does Python do that instead of re-raising the exception, as it would have if `yield` was not before `raise`?

(Apparently Python 3 has fixed this wart, and the function yields a list of [None] as you would expect.)

(The workaround is to store the exception in a variable: `except Exception as e: yield; raise e`)

Comment: Arbitrary code (including code that also raises exceptions) may execute between the `yield` and `raise` statements. I suspect the semantics of keeping a stack of pending exceptions that might be raised would be nearly impossible to define.

Comment: @chepner not at all, the exception could just become a hidden local variable inside the `except` block. If it works in Python 3 then it just sounds like a bug that was fixed.

Comment: The exception is stored on the stack frame for the current thread, but I suspect it is cleared as the `yield` causes the stack frame to be put on hold and control returns to the frame driving the iteration.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is just a bug in Python 2.x. According to the [bug report](http://bugs.python.org/issue7563), the issue is fixed in Python 3, but due to the complexity of backporting it, the fix never made it to 2.7 before it went into maintenance mode:

> This is fixed in Python 3. I don't know if it's worth backporting the
>   changes because it may be hard to avoid also backporting the
>   incompatibilities in the exception model.

Eight months later...

> This won't get backported now that 2.7 is in maintenance.